# Subdivision don't act on particular sides

Tags: modifiers

I've created a monster, but I need to use the subdivision modify to make it look better. When I add it on the mesh it make this strange effect:

This is without
[image: screenshot: no subsurf]

and this is with
[image: screenshot: subsurf - not affecting tail]

how can I make this side smooth like the other?

Comment: Hi, it's hard to tell but it looks like the subdiv modifier is working as intended. What is the topology of the upper surface? Is it one big face with many sides (ngon) or is it subdivided into sections (squares/quads or tris)? If it's the former then subdiv will have a harder time with it.

Comment: Hello, please provide this part of your object (copy paste the URL it will generate): https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: i've uploaded on it, try to figure out what is the problem (the problem is on the back side of the monster... thank you man